# Beginner Poker Program: Traceback and Assertion errors

Tags: python

I'm trying to get this poker program working and it's my first Python program.. I'm having trouble understanding two errors I'm getting as the code looks correct to me.

Using Eclipse/PyDev

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\****\workspace\xfz\src\Unit1.py", line 98, in <module>
    print test()
 File "C:\Documents and Settings\****\workspace\xfz\src\Unit1.py", line 86, in test
    assert card_ranks(sf) == "TC 9C 8C 7C 6C"
AssertionError
```

The code:

```
def poker(hands):
    "Return the best hand: poker([hand,...]) => hand"
    return allmax(hands, key=hand_rank)

def allmax(iterable, key=None):
    "Return a list of all items equal to the max of the iterable."
    result, maxval = [], None
    key = key or (lambda x: x)
    for x in iterable:
        xval = key(x)
        if not result or xval > maxval:
            result, maxval = [x], xval
        elif xval == maxval:
            result.append(x)
    return result

def hand_rank(hand):
    ranks = card_ranks(hand)
    if straight(ranks) and flush(hand):
        return (8, max(ranks)) 
    elif kind(4, ranks):
        return (7, kind(4, ranks), kind(1, ranks)) # 99993 (7,9,3)
    elif kind(3, ranks) and kind(2, ranks):
        return (6, kind(3, ranks) and kind(2, ranks))
    elif flush(hand):
        return (5, ranks)
    elif straight(hand):
        return (4, ranks)
    elif kind(3, ranks):
        return (3, kind(3, ranks), ranks)
    elif two_pair(ranks):
        return (2, two_pair(ranks), ranks)
    elif kind(2, ranks):
        return (1, kind(2, ranks), ranks)
    else:
        return (0, ranks) 

def card_ranks(hand):
    "Return a list of the ranks, sorted with higher first."
    ranks = ['--23456789TJQKA'.index(r) for r,s in hand]
    ranks.sort(reverse=True)
    return [5, 4, 3, 2, 1] if (ranks == [14, 5, 4, 3, 2]) else ranks


def straight(ranks):
    "Return true if the ordered ranks form a 5 card straight"
    return (max(ranks)-min(ranks) == 4) and len(set(ranks)) == 5

def flush(hand):
    "Return True if all the cards have the same suit"
    suits = [s for r,s in hand]
    return len(set(suits)) == 1

def kind(n, ranks):
    for r in ranks:
        if ranks.count(r) == n: return r
    return None

def two_pair(ranks):
    pair = kind(2, ranks)
    lowpair = kind(2, list(reversed(ranks)))
    if pair and lowpair != pair:
        return (pair, lowpair)
    else:
        return None

def test():
    "Test cases for the functions in poker program"
    sf = "6C 7C 8C 9C TC".split() # Straight Flush
    fk = "9D 9H 9S 9C 7D".split() # Four of a Kind
    fh = "TD TC TH 7C 7D".split() # Full House
    tp = "5S 5D 9H 9C 6S".split()
    fkranks = card_ranks(fk)
    tpranks = card_ranks(tp)
    assert kind(4, fkranks) == 9
    assert kind(3, fkranks) == None
    assert kind(2, fkranks) == None
    assert kind(1, fkranks) == 7
    assert two_pair(fkranks) == None
    assert two_pair(tpranks) == (9, 5)
    assert card_ranks(sf) == "TC 9C 8C 7C 6C"
    assert card_ranks(fk) == "9D 9H 9S 9C 7D"
    assert card_ranks(fh) == "TD TC TH 7C 7D"
    assert poker([sf, fk, fh]) == sf
    assert poker([fk, fh]) == fk
    assert poker([fh, fh]) == fh
    assert poker([sf]) == sf
    assert poker([sf] + 99*[fh]) == sf
    assert hand_rank(sf) == (8, 10)
    assert hand_rank(fk) == (7, 9, 7)
    assert hand_rank(fh) == (6, 10, 7)

print test()
```

Comment: Change line 86 to `assert card_ranks(sf) == "TC 9C 8C 7C 6C", card_ranks(sf)` and give the new traceback.

Comment: OK - I changed lines 86-88 to: 'assert card_ranks(sf) == "TC 9C 8C 7C 6C", card_ranks(sf)
    assert card_ranks(fk) == "9D 9H 9S 9C 7D", card_ranks(sf)
    assert card_ranks(fh) == "TD TC TH 7C 7D", card_ranks(sf)' Can you explain what you mean by "and give the new traceback"? Sorry, I'm new to Python and don't really know what that means

Comment: The change I asked you to make would still result in an assertion error, but it would be one that showed you what went wrong. When you do an assert statement you should always give it two arguments. The second argument gets printed by the assertion error. Use it to see what `card_ranks(sf)` actually does equal.

Answer (score 1):

```
    assert card_ranks(sf) == "TC 9C 8C 7C 6C"
```

evaluates to False because

```
    card_ranks(sf) = [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]  != "TC 9C 8C 7C 6C" 

    >>> card_ranks(sf) 
    [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
    >>> card_ranks(fk) 
    [9, 9, 9, 9, 7]
    >>> card_ranks(fh) 
    [10, 10, 10, 7, 7]
```

The function you run is called test() and it tests with assert to make sure, that the statement tested are True. Assert throws an AssertionError and exists the program if any of them is False.

Your next lines are False too:

```
    >>> poker([sf, fk, fh])
    [['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC']]
    >>> sf
    ['6C', '7C', '8C', '9C', 'TC']
    >>> poker([sf, fk, fh]) == sf
    False
```

Hint: run find/replace over your file and replace 'assert' with 'print'

Comment: Getting this error now, not sure what the problem with print() is nor the call on line 89: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\****\workspace\xfv\src\Unit1.py", line 98, in <module>
    print test()
  File "C:\Documents and Settings\****\workspace\xfv\src\Unit1.py", line 89, in test
    assert poker([sf, fk, fh]) == sf
AssertionError

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
assert card_ranks(sf) == "TC 9C 8C 7C 6C"
assert card_ranks(fk) == "9D 9H 9S 9C 7D"
assert card_ranks(fh) == "TD TC TH 7C 7D"
```

to:

```
assert card_ranks(sf) == [10, 9, 8, 7, 6]
assert card_ranks(fk) == [9, 9, 9, 9, 7]
assert card_ranks(fh) == [10, 10, 10, 7, 7]
```

So an easy way to check what's wrong is by putting some print statements. And fundamentally, look at what you are doing. Your card_ranks() function says in the comment that it returns a list, and still you are comparing it to a string. Think a bit more before writing the code. Saves time when debugging.